# Cognito - custom auth request parameter into cognito token

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

we'd like to add custom attributes from the auth request be added as claim into token

Request body:
client_id=someClient&client_secret=someSecret&grant_type=client_credentials&user_claim=t
heClaim

The request is handled by ts lambda, where the AdminInitiateAuthCommand is being sent to client.

I'd like to see the variable user_claim as the attribute in the decoded token. Im calling the authentication from ts lambda:

```
async function authenticate(username: string, password: string) {
    const authenticationCommand = new AdminInitiateAuthCommand({
        UserPoolId: userPoolId,
        AuthFlow: "ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
        ClientId: userPoolClientId,
        AuthParameters: {
            "USERNAME": commonUser,
            "PASSWORD": password
        },
        ClientMetadata: {
            "user_claim": user_claim
        }
    });
```

But according the documentation, ClientMetadata wont appear in PreTokenGenerationTriggerEvent. In fact, it only appears in Pre signup, Pre authentication and User migration.

Is there any solution for this?

The reasoning here is pricing. We expect so many users that the pricing for MAUs would be unbearable. So we are trying to have only one Cognito user with extra added user_claim determining the user trying to log in.

Or is there any other solution of this?

Thanks